# Update on Group By

Tags: mysql

This is the data:

```
Mbr_Rel_Id  Most_Recent COV_START_DATE  START_DATE
93698       NULL        2006-07-01      2006-07-01
93698       NULL        2006-07-01      2008-01-01
93698       NULL        2011-07-01      2011-07-01
93698       NULL        2014-07-01      2014-07-01
44726       NULL        2012-03-01      2012-03-01
44726       NULL        2012-03-01      2017-05-01
```

```
SELECT Mbr_Rel_Id,Most_Recent, COV_START_DATE, START_DATE
FROM tbl_mbr_cov 
WHERE (Mbr_Rel_Id, COV_START_DATE, START_DATE) 
IN 
( SELECT Mbr_Rel_Id, COV_START_DATE, MAX(START_DATE)
  FROM tbl_mbr_cov
GROUP BY 
tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_REL_ID,
tbl_mbr_cov.COV_START_DATE 
)
```

The above query gives me the results I want. I'm grouping on MBR_REL_ID and COV_START_DATE returning the row with the most recent START_DATE. So these are the results:

```
Mbr_Rel_Id  Most_Recent COV_START_DATE  START_DATE
93698       NULL        2006-07-01      2008-01-01
93698       NULL        2011-07-01      2011-07-01
93698       NULL        2014-07-01      2014-07-01
44726       NULL        2012-03-01      2017-05-01
```

I need to update the field, Most_Recent = 1 in the above query results. So what I'm for looks line this:

```
Mbr_Rel_Id  Most_Recent COV_START_DATE  START_DATE
93698       NULL        2006-07-01      2006-07-01
93698       1           2006-07-01      2008-01-01
93698       1           2011-07-01      2011-07-01
93698       1           2014-07-01      2014-07-01
44726       NULL        2012-03-01      2012-03-01
44726       1           2012-03-01      2017-05-01
```

The update query below updates ALL the records shown at the very top, not just the max per group:

```
Update tbl_mbr_cov A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Mbr_Rel_Id,Most_Recent, COV_START_DATE, START_DATE
FROM tbl_mbr_cov 
WHERE (Mbr_Rel_Id, COV_START_DATE, START_DATE) 
IN 
( SELECT Mbr_Rel_Id, COV_START_DATE, MAX(START_DATE)
  FROM tbl_mbr_cov
GROUP BY 
tbl_mbr_cov.MBR_REL_ID,
tbl_mbr_cov.COV_START_DATE 
) )B
ON B.MBR_REL_ID = A.MBR_REL_ID
SET A.Most_Recent = 1
```

How do I structure the update to set Most_Recent = 1 to just those in the max group query above?

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause after the `SET` or maybe a `CASE` try running a fiddle so it's better to see what you are trying to do, what fields you are trying to get, explain it better because I'm just guessing http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Not sure I understand the fiddle thing, but I added sample data above to clarify my post. Hope that explains it.